# Unity Vector2.MoveTowards function is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, vector, dice

Currently, I am making a board game with Unity. The player has to be moved according to the results of rolling dice, but the player always moves one space less in the first turn.
I checked that the dice was thrown well and the results were delivered well, but the player moves one space less, only in the first turn. (For example, assume that you throw the dice for the first turn and get 2, you don't move two spaces, but only one space.)
I put a script called FollowThePath in each player object (soju, beer, whiskey, cocktail), and decide player's order with the GameController.
In addition, waypoints were placed in each board game compartment managed in an array called waypoints. It is the principle of moving by stepping on each waypoint according to the result of throwing dice.
I'll attach the code.help me please.....

[blue dots are waypoints. and the object on bottom right is the player.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUfvJ.jpg)

FollowThePath.cs

```
private void Start()
    {
        transform.position = waypoints[wayPointIndex].transform.position;
        howManyMove = 0;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (moveAllowed)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }
    private void Move()
    {
        if (wayPointIndex <= waypoints.Length - 1)
        {
           
            if (howManyMove < GameControl.yutSideThrown && transform.position == waypoints[wayPointIndex].transform.position)
            {
                isReallyMove = false;
               
                if (wayPointIndex == 5)
                    wayPointIndex += 15;
                else if (wayPointIndex == 10)
                    wayPointIndex += 15;
                else if (wayPointIndex == 22)
                    wayPointIndex += 6;
                else if (wayPointIndex == 27)
                    wayPointIndex -= 4;
                else if (wayPointIndex == 24)
                    wayPointIndex -= 9;
                else wayPointIndex += 1;
                //말을 실제로 몇번 움직였는지 나타내는 변수
                howManyMove += 1;
                
            }
            
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[wayPointIndex].transform.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            
            if (transform.position == waypoints[wayPointIndex].transform.position)
            {
               
                Debug.Log("Moved");
            }
            isReallyMove = true;
        
        }

    }
}
```

GameControl.cs

```
void Start()
    {   
        //각 player 변수에 object들 연결하는 코드
        player1 = GameObject.Find("soju");
        player2 = GameObject.Find("beer");
        player3 = GameObject.Find("whiskey");
        player4 = GameObject.Find("cocktail");
        //자기 차례에 moveAllowed가 true가 되어야함. 그래서 초기화는 false로
        player1.GetComponent<FollowThePath>().moveAllowed = false;
        player2.GetComponent<FollowThePath>().moveAllowed = false;
        player3.GetComponent<FollowThePath>().moveAllowed = false;
        player4.GetComponent<FollowThePath>().moveAllowed = false;
        whoWinsText.text = "";
        whosTurn.text = "소주 팀 차례!";
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        if(player1.GetComponent<FollowThePath>().howManyMove >= yutSideThrown && player1.GetComponent<FollowThePath>().isReallyMove)
        {
            whosTurn.text = "맥주 팀 차례!";
            player1.GetComponent<FollowThePath>().howManyMove = 0;
            player1.GetComponent<FollowThePath>().moveAllowed = false;
        }
...
```

please help me!TT

Comment: In general instead of `Update` you might want to use a Coroutine .. that is easier to control/maintain and you wouldn't need so many checks and flags

Comment: So I think I loosely understand your desired outcome, but what is currently happening? what are you specifically asking? Try re-formatting this question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Try debug logging out the index, to make sure it is valid/what you are expecting. Does the  Debug.Log("Moved"); ever get called?

Comment: where do you set moveAllowed = true? I see you set them each to false in the start...

Comment: @NCarlson doesn't sound like that's part of the issue though .. it is probably happening once the dice was thrown (this part is not in the given code snippets)

Comment: It may be part of the issue, if it isn't ever set to true then move() will never be called? I'm still not sure I understand what the problem is exactly, is " the player moves one space less, only in the first turn" not the intended result / the problem? If so then its probably the first thing I mentioned : mishandling of the index .

Comment: @NCarlson I mean, when I through the dice in the beginning, and assume that  the result was 2, but player move only 1. And when I through dice for second time and got 4, the player moves 4 normally. And the Debug.Log("Moved"); does not call properly only in the beginning.